# Does "iX" sometimes stand for analytics?

Tags: analytics, data-modeling, branding

Does "iX" sometimes stand for analytics? The context I am referring to is company names, project names, blog names, etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's an abbreviation commonly used for analytics. I was previously the co-founder of an analytics company and have never heard iX used in any context.

A quick Google search shows no mention at all of iX related to analytics in general, but there is a company called InfomatiX (http://infomatix.net/) that has several products branded with IX.